# Beginner: Discounting underlying bias in order to perform regression analysis

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have multi year data of the mean speed of varying size boats to make an ocean crossing. I also know the underlying mean of the average current speed, this is sometimes in favour of the ships and sometimes against on a day-day basis but I only have each specific years mean. (75% Positive, 25% Negative for each year).

I then have various other data, power, weight, dynamics etc..

Before I look into the effect of this data I wanted to remove the bias of the current, but was not sure what tool or approach would be best since I lack the daily current speed..